# About reciprocal of algebraically independent sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $S$ and $E$ be two algebraically independent sets over $\Bbb Q$  such that $S\cup E$ is algebraically independent. Consider $$ A:=\{1/s\colon s\in S\} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ B:=\{1/e\colon e\in E\}$$  I know $A$ and $B$ algebraically independent. Moreover, $A\cup E$ and $S\cup B$ are both algebraically independent. I am not quite sure about the following

> Is $A\cup B$ algebraically independent?

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: You can clear denominators to turn a polynomial relation among the $\frac{1}{s}$'s and $\frac{1}{e}$'s into a polynomial relation among the $s$'s and $e$'s.

Comment: @Dave, So, they are. Right?

Comment: That's right.${}{}{}{}$